# How to use JndiPropertySource?

Tags: java, spring, jndi

We are trying to convert our WebApp to complete configuration using a [`JndiPropertySource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jndi/JndiPropertySource.html)(for all parameters that are environment dependent).

Has anyone a example usage of it (maybe even for tomcat)?

We already get the `DataSource` via JNDI, so we want the `HibernateDialect` to be configured right besides it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `spring-context.xml` you need only the placeholder tag:

```
<context:property-placeholder />
```

After that you insert an environment tag in Tomcats main `context.xml`, it reads it:

```
<Environment name="hibernate.dialect" 
            value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" 
             type="java.lang.String" 
         override="false"/>
```

Now you can use the code `${hibernate.dialect}` in the sprinng config file.

Comment: What about `name="hibernate/dialect"`, which ist more common in JNDI? Later, in Spring, `${hibernate/dialect}` does not seem to work.

Comment: I have experienced that JNDI treats hibernate/dialect and hibernate.dialect as being two ways to express the same. I believe this is not true for spring...